# Bootstrap navigation not working link not showing up

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

So for some reason the "Home" button or link does not show up on nav bar. if there is any advice on how to get this to work it would be super helpful. Thanks!

(this is different question. I have not seen any question with this same problem)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Title</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>


 <div class="container" id="main">






    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">

     <div class="container">

      <a class="nav-brand" href="">LOGO HERE</a>

      <div class=" nav_collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

       <li>
        <a href="">Home</a>

       </li>

       </ul>
      </div>




    </div>

</div>



    <div class= "carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
     
    </div>



    <div class="row" id = "bigCallout">
     
    </div>



    <div class="row" id="featureHeading">

    </div>

    <div class="row" id="features">

    </div>


    <div class="row" id="moreInfo">

    </div>



    <div class="row" id="moreCourses">

    </div>


 </div>

























    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with the collapse?

If you simply do this:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Logo Here</a>
    <div class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The home link shows up. Do you want it in a collapsable menu?